# Why doesn't my sticky footer stick?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've browsed to all question related to "sticky footer" and nothing helped me because my #content div does not always have sufficient content to push the footer to the bottom. Here is the code I've used to achieve this, but apparently I did something wrong:

```css
html, body, div#container { height: 100%; }
body > div#container { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
div#index_body { padding-bottom: 30px; }

.footer { 
    clear: both; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 10; 
    height: 30px; 
    margin-top: -45px; 
    padding-top:15px;
}

.footer { 
    color: #666;
    background-color:#F4F7FA;
    border-top:1px solid #E6E7E8; 
    font-size:95%;
    text-align: center;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="index_body">
    </div><!--end index_body -->
    <div id="index_footer" class="footer">
    </div><!--end footer -->
</div><!--end container -->
```

Some of my attempts work when index body has loads of text images only then the footer goes to the end but when it doesn't have much content let say 2 paragraph tags and an image the footer doesn't stick. Maybe this is not possible with just CSS, because the index_footer height is not fixed? Is there a way to do this with JavaScript? Or what is the right way to do this?

My screen resolution is really big maybe that is the problem its 1680 x 1050

Comment: I often use http://www.digital-web.com/extras/positioning_101/css_positioning_example.php for issues like these as it has almost every example of positioning I can think of and degrades gracefully too

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your footer div outside of the container div. Your technique should then work. The way you have it set at the moment the footer is within the containing div, but positioned relatively. So even though the containing div may have 100% height, the footer div within it is still only to go just below the content in the container.

A quick example of what I mean, (*note that an extra div with some `padding-bottom` is required in order to make sure the footer does not overlap the contents*),

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sticky Footer Test</title>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        * { 
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #container {
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height/**/: 100%; /* for IE6 */
            background: #ddd;
        }

        #footer {
            position: relative;
            background: #555;
            margin-top: -100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #content {
            padding-bottom: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Hello! I'm some content!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Hello! I'm a footer!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you can't move the footer outside of the container (for whatever reason), then you could also try positioning the footer absolutely within the containing div to be at the bottom. `position: absolute; bottom: 0px;` etc

For example, (*again, an extra div with some `padding-bottom` is required in order to make sure the footer does not overlap the contents*),

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sticky Footer Test 2</title>

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        * { 
            margin: 0px;
        }

        #container {
            position: relative;
            min-height: 100%;
            height: auto !important;
            height/**/: 100%; /* for IE6 */
            background: #ddd;
        }

        #footer {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            background: #555;
            margin-top: -100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        #content {
            padding-bottom: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <p>Hello! I'm some content!</p>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Hello! I'm a footer!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your examples, but there is one slight thing which isn't good, when you resize the window the footer overlaps the content.

Comment: @Gandalf: Ah yes, I see what you mean. You should just be able to wrap the content in another div and give it a bottom-padding of 100px;. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Answer now updated so that both examples won't overlap content. Since you say you can't move the footer outside the container, then the second example would be the one you want to go for.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your exact question, but the [work done by Ryan Fait](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) has worked very well for me across multiple browsers.  You might want to give this a try (or take a look at what he did compared to what you are doing and see if you can determine a fix).

Comment: Oh I've try this for so many times, like zilion combinations .. problem is because somethimes I don't have enough content in my container so the footer doesn't stick, sometimes I have too much content and then footer sticks over the content instead at the bottom and sometimes I just have enough to stick it properly, maybe in my case I need to use javascript

Answer (score 1):

I believe the root of the problem is that the footer element in the HTML needs to be outside of the #container div. Also, I noticed after I removed that, issues with margin and padding on the body tag. Finally, the border-top on the .footer makes the height of the footer 46px, not 45px...

The corrected CSS:

```
/* FOOTER FIX */
html, body, div#container { height: 100%; }
body > div#container { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }
div#index_body { padding-bottom: 30px; }

body{margin:0;padding:0;}
#container{ margin-bottom: -46px; }
.footer { 
    clear: both; 
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 10; 
    height: 30px; 
    padding-top:15px;
    color: #666;
    background-color:#F4F7FA;
    border-top:1px solid #E6E7E8; 
    font-size:95%;
    text-align: center;  
}    /* END FIX */
```

The corrected HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="index_body">
        </div><!--end index_body -->
    </div><!--end container -->
    <div id="index_footer" class="footer">
    </div><!--end footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easy, here's the minimum required template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>SO question 1980857</title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }
            #container {
                position: relative;
                min-height: 100%;
            }
            * html #container {
                height: 100%; /* This is min-height for IE6. */
            }
            #footer {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            #footer, #pushfooter {
                height: 50px; /* Both must have the same height. */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">Content</div>
            <div id="pushfooter"></div>
            <div id="footer">Footer</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Making the container `relative` and giving it a `min-height` will actually stick the footer to its bottom all the time regardless of the content's actual height, which was your major concern as understood from comments.

Comment: ok it does indeed push it to the bottom of the website but there is some blank space left below, how do I get rid of that ?

Comment: I mean the unecessary scroller appers if you know what I mean .. I don't need to have scroller at all but it appers because of the empty blank space below footer

Comment: The scroller is caused by using elements with top and bottom margins instead of paddings inside the `#container`. Margins aren't taken into the height, they goes beyond the height. You should use padding instead. Also, ensure that you set the following in CSS to remove default margins: `p, div { margin: 0;}`. Once again, copypaste the above example and run it. You'll see no scroller. Just build further based on this template.

Comment: hmm its not working again the same thing, you see I don't build the website from the beginning I'm just doing some final touches, thank you anyways you get a vote up, I'll try again tommorrow , feeling preaty tired now. tnx again

Comment: There may be more elements which play a role. Just verify the entire CSS that you didn't specify any top/bottom margins, for example headers, lists, etc. inside the `#container`. Otherwise you need to increment the `#pushfooter`'s height accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Going off Harmen, i have tested this and it works, with the footer in the container. altho it is a little hackish

**CSS**

```
html, body, div#container { height: 100%; }
body > div#container { height: auto; min-height: 100%; }

div#index_body { 
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -46px;
}

.footer, .push {
  height: 30px;
}

.footer { 
  clear: both; 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 10; 
  margin: 0px;
}

.footer { 
  color: #666;
  background-color:#F4F7FA;
  border-top:1px solid #E6E7E8; 
  font-size:95%;
  text-align: center;  

   }    /* END FIX */
```

**html**

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="index_body">
        <div class="push"></div><!--Used to force the footer down to avoid overlap of footer and text -->
</div><!--end index_body -->
<div id="index_footer" class="footer">
</div><!--end footer -->
</div><!--end container -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to realize a sticky footer, that is a footer placed in a fixed position at the bottom of the webpage that doesn't move when your scroll the page you can use this css code:

```
#footer{
position:fixed;
clear:both;
}
```

position:fixed makes the footer sticky anyway there could be floating problems if you used float:left or float:right in your code before, so using also clear:both it clears the floating and ensures that the footer is at the bottom under other divs and not on the left or right of the precedent div.

Comment: A bit of explanation would make our answer much better.

Comment: @AnupCowkur done. Thanks for your suggestion. I replied to the same type of question posted by different people and i forgot giving an explaination this time. Anyway i usually do. Hope my answer can help many.

Answer (score -1):

This will work, no matter what the height of the #container is:

**CSS:**

```
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    #container {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: auto !important;
        height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -50px;
        position: relative;
    }

    #index_footer {
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        position: relative;
        background: #CCC;
    }

    #push {
        height: 50px;
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="index_body">
        test
    </div>
    <div id="push"> </div>
</div>
<div id="index_footer" class="footer">
    test
</div>
```