# How to keep <footer> always at the bottom of page,( not screen) in html5

Tags: html, css

I know this is may be a old question, But I have tried many way, if the content of is light such as 2 row, the footer will come up and leave a lot of space. Here is my code:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
<body>
  <div class='navbar'></div>
  <div class='maincontent'> main content</div>
  <footer class='footer-box'>
    footer content
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I try to set position to either relative or absolute but none of them works fine for me, I need to always position the footer at the bottom of page, no-matter the content of maincontent. any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're contradicting yourself. If there's only a little content, then that *is* the bottom of the page, but you appear to want the footer at the bottom of the screen. Anyway I'm 99% sure this is a dupe multiple times over (see the related links on the right).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sticky footer question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980857/sticky-footer-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want to have the footer at the bottom of the viewport, unless the main content is big enough to reach it, in which case you want the footer to come at the bottom of the page.

In my opinion, this is the best/cleanest way to do that:

<sup>**Note that this is not a JavaScript solution, I have added the JS so you can see the effect of a growing `.maincontent` block. Run the code snippet below to see what I mean.**</sup>

```js
function addContent() {

  $('.maincontent').append('<p>more content</p>');

}
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.maincontent {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  /* or the footer height */
}
.footer-box {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <div class='navbar'>
    <button onclick="javascript:addContent()">add content</button>
  </div>
  <div class='maincontent'>main content</div>
  <footer class='footer-box'>
    footer content
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using bootstrap, so this will work for you

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    </div>
```

Comment: how can you tell OP is using [tag:bootstrap]?

Comment: navbar is rarely used unless bootstrap is involved

Answer (score 0):

Even if the question is answered I want to propose a solution with flexboxes.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}

footer{
  height: 70px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main>
  Main content
</main>

<footer>
  Footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

**add css property to the footer element:**

```
.footer-box{
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
}
```

LIVE [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qg3eLL3q/)

Comment: i don´t understand the downvote of my answer... the solution i have giving is working and correct.. !!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
footer.footer-box {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Why did it get -1 ? It's exactly the answer to the problem "I need to always position the footer at the bottom of page, no-matter the content of maincontent."