# Sticky footer with include php

Tags: php, html, css, footer, sticky

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/ccs" href="css/indexcss.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
    <?php
        include("utilbar.php");
        include("navbar.php");
    ?>
    </div>

    <?php 
        if (isset($_GET["type"])) {
            $page = $_GET["type"];
        }
        else {
            $page = "home";
        }

        //echo "<body onload=\"changeContent('".$page."')\">";
    ?>

    <!--script>
    function contentOnload() {
        window.location.href('content.php');
    }
    </script-->

    <script>
    function navClick(contentName)
    {
        window.location.href = "index.php?type=" + contentName;
    }
    </script>

    <div class="container">
    <?php include($page.".php"); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <?php include("footer.html"); ?>    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS here:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

So I'm trying to get a footer to stick under the content of all my includes, but sometimes it jumps above the content of the included file. I've looked up most possible sticky footer guides and tried to apply them, but none seem to work like they should. I've been trying to fix this for a while now.

Here's the footer HTML CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/footercss.css">
    <title>Footer</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="containerf">
    <div id="logos"></div>
    <div id="foottext">
        <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png" height="25" width="25"></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" height="25" width="25"></a>
        <a href="http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/fbtrp.png" height="25" width="25"></a>   
        <b>| Schaafstraat 137 | &copy; 2016 Kopala | All rights reserved.</b>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

#containerf {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background-color: #006666;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 500px;
}

#foottext {
    line-height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #d9d9d9;
}

#foottext img {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: *"Here's the footer html css"* - why is there HTML markup and CSS in that file? there should only be your divs. Question's unclear as to what body of code is what filenames.

Comment: Look at your (rendered) HTML source and you'll see what I mean, it'll be a mess.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sticky footer question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980857/sticky-footer-question)

Comment: I've cleaned up the formatting here a bit. Next time, format it before you post to make it easier for people to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

In which file did you set the .footer to bottom:0; ? It seems that you declared it in a regular style.css but in the fotter.htm you include footercss.css

You should paste the bottom:0; to the footercss.css

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions. [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @JayBlanchard maybe that's the only way that people get responses from OP's nowaways. *sigh*